# How to train an NER model with different beam objective parameters in Spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I'm attempting to update a pre-trained spacy model `en_core_web_md` with a few rounds of a beam objective other than `beam_width = 1`, and I cannot seem to find the right way to pass the different parameters into the `**cfg` such that the model uses them for training (at [THIS](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/syntax/nn_parser.pyx#L137-L142) point).

This was my latest attempt:

```
pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
# only train NER
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes), warnings.catch_warnings():
    # show warnings for misaligned entity spans once
    warnings.filterwarnings("once", category=UserWarning, module='spacy')

    # TRY TO FORCE BEAM TRAINING INSTEAD OF GREEDY METHOD
    nlp.use_params({'ner':{'beam_width':16, 'beam_density':0.0001}})
    print(nlp.meta) 

    sizes = compounding(1.0, 4.0, 1.001)
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
    for itn in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA_2)
        batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA_2, size=sizes)
        losses = {}
        for batch in batches:
            texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
            nlp.update(texts, 
            annotations, 
            sgd=optimizer, 
            drop=0.35, 
            losses=losses
            )
        print("Losses", losses)
```

However, after training, the `model/ner/cfg` file still lists:

```
{
"beam_width":1,
"beam_density":0.0,
"beam_update_prob":1.0,
...
```

So, I have a few questions:

1. Am I able to update an existing greedy trained model with a new beam objective?
2. If true, how can I properly changed these training parameters (and confirm they are changed)?
3. If false, for a new from scratch model, how can I properly changed these training parameters (and confirm they are changed)?

**Why do this?**
I am attempting to train a model that provides probabilities for NER decisions that I can surface to my users.  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877735/how-to-get-probability-of-prediction-per-entity-from-spacy-ner-model) post and a few others show how to use beam_parse to obtain probabilities after the fact from a greedy model.  However, they all mention that the greedy model hasn't been trained with a global objective, so these scores aren't especially meaningful unless you also perform some iterations of beam training as well. ([link to github issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2601))

Comment: Do you initiate training with something like `nlp.resume_training(**cfg)` or `nlp.begin_training(**cfg)`? Did you try to pass your params there?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I tried `nlp.resume_training( beam_width=16, beam_density=0.0001)` and  `spacy.load(model, beam_width=16, beam_density=0.0001) `.  Both complete a model run, but the cfg file in the results show beam_width=1.

Comment: I also tried `nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35, losses=losses, component_cfg = {'ner':{'beam_width':16, 'beam_density':0.0001}})` which fails to run, because 'ner.update' does not allow additional arguments ([src code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/d844030fd880165f08bf88f4fd386ef878e63360/spacy/syntax/nn_parser.pyx#L388))

Comment: Try posting your question at https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues.

Comment: done. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5915

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316842/change-beam-width-in-spacy-ner). This is the syntax for modifying config parameters.

```
nlp.entity.cfg['beam_width'] = 16
nlp.entity.cfg['beam_density'] = 0.0001
```

I put these lines ahead of `optimizer = nlp.resume_training()`, and the values were used in training.